# dismissViewControllerAnimated: completion: has no effect

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller

Has anyone seen this before?  In the iPad simulator, I have an About view controller.  I want to present it modally, and have the user click a close button.

To complicate it a bit, I have a main View Controller, that presents an iAd banner and a "Main Menu" view controller.  The button is on the main menu, and so the IBAction is sent to the Main menu view controller.

In the Main Menu VC, I have a property pointing to the app View Controller, so I call:

```
AboutViewController *about = [[AboutViewController alloc] initWithNibName:....];
about.callingViewController = viewController;
[viewController presentViewController:about animated:YES completion:nil];
```

So then in the About View Controller, I have an IBAction that dismisses it:

```
- (void) dismissAbout:(id)sender
{
    [callingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When the dismissAbout is called, nothing happens - the view doesn't go away, and no output in the debugger console.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBAction should be

```
- (IBAction) dismissAbout:(id)
```

secondly you are dimissing the aboutController so should use `self` instead of `callingViewController`

Comment: Also @ssantos, that was it, I had to message self.  (The .h declares dismissAbout as IBAction, while the .m declares it as void.  IBAction is an alias for void.)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to call

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers say, you can use [self dismiss...] because that message is automatically forwarded to the presenting view controller. You also could use [self.presentingViewController dismiss..] because a modal controller has a presentingViewController property that points to the view controller that presented you. There's no need to create and pass the callingViewController.